# I am up to face it X I am ready to face it

Tags: sentence-construction

When someone asks if I would be able to face a full time job, can I answer with the following sentences?

1. I am ready to face the challenge.
2. I am up for it.
3. I am up to face it.
4. I am up for facing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. "I am ready to face the challenge." - Grammatically correct but a bit unnatural. It may sound a bit overkeen, potentially bordering on sarcasm in some situations. I would expect to hear this in a motivational advert or something like that instead of normal conversation.
2. "I am up for it." - Natural response, sounds good. Maybe a little bit informal but fine in nearly all spoken English.

3 and 4. I would understand these clearly and they are grammatically correct but I have never heard anyone say them. I can't really put my finger on why but they seem a bit unnatural.

Comment: Option 4 seems a bit more natural to me than 3 which is borderline ungrammatical. Options 1 and 2 are as you say the ones to go for.